# Using a join instead of subquery

Tags: postgresql, join, subquery

For this question:
   Get the  pids of products ordered through     any agent who makes     at least one order for a customer  in Kyoto. Use joins this time; no sub-queries.

I was able to get the answer using a subquery:

```
select distinct pid
from orders
where aid in (
     select aid 
     from orders
     where cid in(
         select cid
         from customers
         where city = 'Kyoto'
                 ) 
              )
```

I cannot figure out how to do this using only joins however.
This code returns the aid's that i need to get the pid's however i can't come up with a way to get them without using a sub query:

```
select distinct o.aid
from orders o, customers c
where o.cid = c.cid
and c.city = 'Kyoto'
```

Here are the two tables i am using:

Customers:

```
 cid name city discount
 c001 Tiptop Duluth 10.00
 c002 Basics Dallas 12.00
 c003 Allied Dallas 8.00
 c004 ACME Duluth 8.00
 c005 Weyland-Yutani Acheron 0.00
 c006 ACME Kyoto 0.00
```

and Orders:

```
 ordno mon cid aid pid qty dollars
 1011 jan c001 a01 p01 1000 450.00
 1013 jan c002 a03 p03 1000 880.00
 1015 jan c003 a03 p05 1200 1104.00
 1016 jan c006 a01 p01 1000 500.00
 1017 feb c001 a06 p03 600 540.00
 1018 feb c001 a03 p04 600 540.00
 1019 feb c001 a02 p02 400 180.00
 1020 feb c006 a03 p07 600 600.00
 1021 feb c004 a06 p01 1000 460.00
 1022 mar c001 a05 p06 400 720.00
 1023 mar c001 a04 p05 500 450.00
 1024 mar c006 a06 p01 800 400.00
 1025 apr c001 a05 p07 800 720.00
 1026 may c002 a05 p03 800 740.00
```

Comment: Homework assignment? It's OK to ask about homework, but it's best to say if it is.

Comment: The way agency relationships work is not at all clear to me from the data and your exisiting query. It looks like you probably just need an innner self-join on orders, an inner join on customer and a filter, but it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Yeah it's homework, it's a lab assignment for a database class. I've managed to get the answer to all the other questions, just need a little help with this one